# Not open URL in Ext.TabPanel autoLoad?

Tags: url, extjs, autoload, tabpanel

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){

var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    enableTabScroll: true,
    activeTab: 0,
    items: [
            {
                title: 'Просмотр информации',
                autoLoad:{url: 'tab1.htm', scripts : true}
            },{
                title: 'Редактирование',
                autoLoad:{url: 'tab3.htm', scripts : false}
               }
    ]

  });



});
```

if i open second tab or other then this error show:

> Cannot read property 'dom' of null

Answer (score 1):

Witch Ex JS version do you using ?
If its >4.0, I think you should write something like that:

```
 var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    enableTabScroll: true,
    activeTab: 0,
    items: [
            {
                    title: 'Просмотр информации',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    autoShow: true,
                    url: 'tab1.htm', 
                    scripts : true
            },{
                    title: 'Редактирование',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    autoShow: true,
                    url: 'tab1.htm', 
                    scripts : false
               }
    ]

  });
```